# Bind buttons for + or - mouse wheel

Tags: javascript

Recently I got an edited version of the JavaScript ["Reel"](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) by Pisi, which allows the user to use the mouse wheel to zoom in on a picture. The "reel" itself is working as a 360 view of an object, using many images which will jump to the next image in order when using mouse drag.

However, since I will use this application on a touch screen without a mouse I was thinking about rebinding the mouse wheel or adding events to a button which works like the mouse wheel. For example, below the DIV with the 360-slider I want two buttons, one that zooms in and one that zooms out. Any idea on how to make this work?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest using hammerJS multitouch events (pinch event) to make it touch friendly, instead of buttons.

Comment: Awesome! I will look into it and see if it will work with Pisi's Reel.